# Windows Script to Daily Update of Folders/Files

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-scripting, windows-task-scheduler

Windows Box Script Creation:

I'm trying to create a script on a windows box that will be used to daily via task scheduler. The script would be a shortcut created by a script at midnight each night which points a dated folder (2016-05-18) to another folder such as CurrentDay

Current Path where folders are being created under a daily folder Ex. 
D:\this\is\a\path\2016-05-16

I would need to create a shortcut in a script to have each dated file point to a current day file.
Script to create this new folder called 'CurrentDay'
D:\this\is\a\path\CurrentDay

I would use the current day folder to monitor alerts on a daily basis but at 11:59PM each day I would need the current day files to be removed to the next day files will be added for monitoring. This would be a daily script to only monitor current day files.

Below is something that I have but I'm sure I'm way off from what would be correct.

```
       mkdir D:\this\is\a\path\CurrentDay
       #REM Remove files older than 1 day
       forfiles /p "mkdir D:\this\is\a\path\CurrentDay" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -1
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Show some code and you'll probably get help with issues you're having.

Comment: What you described doesn't make much sense to me. If you're going to have a folder "CurrentDay" folder anyway, why not simply rename or remove the existing folder and create a new one?

Comment: Why not log *to the event log*? Why not make a folder for each day and not use CurrentDay at all because any script can find the current date to know where to look? Why not make CurrentDay a junction, then you won't have to move a days worth of logs every day?